# codeigniter-restserver: digest auth always returns "invalid credentials"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

**I'm attempting to integrate the codeigniter-restserver code into my existing CI3 project. I can not figure out how to get working credentials past authentication.**

**Here's the code it's getting stuck on (REST_Controller.php):**

```
    if (strcasecmp($digest['response'], $valid_response) !== 0)
    {
        // Display an error response
        $this->response([
                $this->config->item('rest_status_field_name') => "false",
                $this->config->item('rest_message_field_name') => $this->lang->line('text_rest_invalid_credentials')
            ], self::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```

**rest.php // config**

```
$config['rest_auth'] = 'digest';
$config['auth_source'] = 'library';
$config['auth_library_class'] = 'auth_model';
$config['auth_library_function'] = 'validate_user';
```

**The class mentioned above (auth from database):**

```
function validate_user($username='',$password=null)
    {
        if($username!=''&&$password!=null)
        {
            $this->db->select('md5');
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $query = $this->db->get('user');
            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result[0]['md5']; // stored as md5(username:realm:password);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**response json:**

```
{"status":"false","error":"Invalid credentials"}
```

**Using postman and here is how I have that setup for a header:**

```
Digest username="user", realm="REST API", nonce="", uri="/restapi/dashboard", response="928e85782ff2322fd2232ebbac4f058f", opaque=""
```

Comment: Where do you define your class auth_model ? The error i have says it cannot find my requested class. My class is put in the libraries folder.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you include  `qop=auth` in autho

Answer (score 0):

@Japheth is right, but you should add Nonce, Nonce Count, and Client Nonce a value blank will do.

```
nonce=" "  // Nonce
nc=" "     // Nonce Count
cnonce=" " // Client Nonce
qop=auth
```

The header will look like the following:

```
Authorization:Digest username="user", realm="REST API", nonce=" ", uri="/restapi/dashboard", qop=auth, nc= , cnonce=" ", response="928e85782ff2322fd2232ebbac4f058f", opaque=""
```